# How to add sorting layer via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm trying add sorting layer via script.

Can I add sorting layer via script? And how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some tests, i find the way.

To adding sorting layer we need access to it's container.

`Sorting Layer` is part of the `TagManager.asset` Object. (at reletive path on `ProjectSettings` directory.)

This code can get TagManager as `SerializedObject` to modify it.

```
var serializedObject = new SerializedObject(AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath("ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset"));
```

To get `SortingLayer` array we must Use below code:

```
var sortingLayers = serializedObject.FindProperty("m_SortingLayers");
```

We first check that our target `SortingLayer` does not exist in the array.

```
var layerName = "SomeLayer";

for (int i = 0; i < sortingLayers.arraySize; i++)
{
    if (sortingLayers.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).FindPropertyRelative("name").stringValue.Equals(layerName))
        return; // this mean target sorting layer exist and we don't need to add it.
}
```

Now add it if does not exist :

```
sortingLayers.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(sortingLayers.arraySize);
var newLayer = sortingLayers.GetArrayElementAtIndex(sortingLayers.arraySize - 1);
newLayer.FindPropertyRelative("name").stringValue = layerName;
newLayer.FindPropertyRelative("uniqueID").intValue = layerName.GetHashCode(); /* some unique number */
```

Don't forget to apply to source:

```
serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```

---

All of top code can compress to bellow method:

```
public static void CreateSortingLayer(string layerName)
{
    var serializedObject = new SerializedObject(AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath("ProjectSettings/TagManager.asset"));
    var sortingLayers = serializedObject.FindProperty("m_SortingLayers");
    for (int i = 0; i < sortingLayers.arraySize; i++)
        if (sortingLayers.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).FindPropertyRelative("name").stringValue.Equals(layerName))
            return;
    sortingLayers.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(sortingLayers.arraySize);
    var newLayer = sortingLayers.GetArrayElementAtIndex(sortingLayers.arraySize - 1);
    newLayer.FindPropertyRelative("name").stringValue = layerName;
    newLayer.FindPropertyRelative("uniqueID").intValue = layerName.GetHashCode(); /* some unique number */
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting! After 2 years, is this still the only way?!

Comment: After using your code, I stumbled on a small problem: occasionally `.GetHashCode()` created -ve `int` id's which causes a problem with any `SortingGroup` that's created. I changed the unique id line to `newLayer.FindPropertyRelative("uniqueID").intValue = (int)System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;`